# Change output (sink) using the terminal

Tags: terminal, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I've made the change from Gnome to i3, and I want to be able to switch my audio output (from headphones to HDMI and vice versa) using the terminal.

```
$ pactl list cards | grep profile
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-surround, output:hdmi-surround71
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1, output:hdmi-surround-extra1
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
            Part of profile(s): output:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

Shouldn't my headphones be in the output above?

```
$ pactl list cards | grep headphones
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
```

My attempt to change from headphones to HDMI:

```
$ pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
$ pulseaudio -k # Should this be necessary?
```

Nothing changes. Is there anything else I have to do? Changing output/sink is extremely easy using the Gnome settings, as it's just a matter of choosing either my headphones or my HDMI output.

*Update with some more information:*

```
$ pacmd list-sinks | grep -A 1 index
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo>
--
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>

$ pacmd set-default-sink 0 # Does nothing as far as I can tell
```

*Update:*

```
$ pacmd set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo && pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -D
```

The above turns off all sound. This turns it on again (through the headphones):

```
$ pacmd set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo && pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -D
```

Comment: Normally HDMI and analog show as different cards... does yours? If so, you'd probably use `pacmd set-default-sink`

Comment: @derobert `$ pacmd set-default-sink 0` didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Did it give an error? Or just do nothing useful? (Also, that's not going to move a client that is currently connected; you need to use different commands to do that.)

Comment: `$ pacmd set-default-sink 0 && pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -D` turns of all sound though, until I set the sink to 1 again. I assume it changes the sink? There's no sound from my HDMI output though.

Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: Is sink 0 the right one? Note BTW that you can also use the names (e.g., `pacmd set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo`).

Comment: It should be the right one, yes. `$ pacmd set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo && pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -D` doesn't work either.

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure why that doesn't work. (Hopefully someone else will come along and know.) BTW: `pulseaudio -k` should not be needed.